# How can I leave the comment update using the Zendesk Zaf api in editing mode?

Tags: javascript, zendesk

I have an app in Zendesk (sidebar) which edits a ticket that has been created so far, well my code (I have used ZAF api client // client.request), but now I want it to leave that update in editing mode and not modify it and send directly, any ideas to achieve this?

I have tried client.request to update the ticket and then client.set to make the request to update it but it does not work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found the solution, I was doing this modification with the ZAF api but it was simpler than what I did, to put the update in the ticket editor you have to use: var client = ZAFClient.init();
client.invoke('ticket.comment.appendText', 'write the text you want'); and not "client.set" like I did. Thanks you anyway.

https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/apps/app-developer-guide/using-the-apps-framework/

Comment: You could flag the answer as valid for future readers